# Regex extract string only contains img tag between span tags

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have requirement to fetch only images which are under anchor and span tags.
Can some one provide solution to fetch images. 
Thanks in advance.

details:
sample code link: http://regexr.com/v1?38u5g

RegEx1: `<a (.*?)><span (.*?)>(.*?)<\/span><\/a>`

RegEx2: `<a (.*?)><span (.*?)><img(.*?) \/><\/span><\/a>`

sample Code:

```
 <span style="font-size: 1.2em;">We voted for our next selection as well. The choice was between Joan Didion's </span><a href="http://www.randomhouse.com/knopf/catalog/results2.pperl?authorid=7051"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">The Year of Magical Thinking</span></a><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">, Sarah Dunant's </span><a href="http://www.randomhouse.com/catalog/display.pperl?isbn=9781588365507"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">In the Company of the Courtesan</span></a><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">, </span><a href="http://www.jodipicoult.com/"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">Jodi Picoult's</span></a> <a href="http://www.simonsays.com/content/book.cfm?tab=1&amp;pid=504542"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">My Sister's Keeper</span></a><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">, Jhumpa Lahiri's </span><a href="http://http//www.houghtonmifflinbooks.com/catalog/titledetail.cfm?titleNumber=694004"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">The Namesake</span></a><span style="font-size: 1.2em;"> and </span><a href="http://www.randomhouse.com/catalog/display.pperl?isbn=9780385721813&amp;view=rg"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">When the Emperor Was Divine</span></a><span style="font-size: 1.2em;"> by Julie Otsuka. </span><a href="http://bookclubgirl.typepad.com/photos/uncategorized/2007/04/19/joan_didion.jpg"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;"><img style="float: left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;" title="Joan_didion" src="joan_didion.jpg" alt="Joan_didion" width="100" height="88" border="0" /></span></a><span style="font-size: 1.2em;"> Joan Didion was the clear winner though many of us are approaching it with some trepidation as we know it will be a very emotional read. Perhaps we'll make a field trip to see the </span><a href="http://www.magicalthinkingonbroadway.com/"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">play</span></a><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">. Kudos to R. who hosted with excellent fare (thank goodness as it served as my dinner) and who served an amazing </span><a href="http://www.cnn.com/FOOD/news/9904/15/cookbook.awards/recipe1.html"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">lemon olive oil cake</span></a><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">. It sounds weird, but is delicious.</span>
```

Regards,
Faruq Shaik.

Comment: Generally parsing HTML (or XML) with regular expression leads to [madness](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392) because SGML derived markup languages are not regular. However if your need is sufficiently narrow *and* the input HTML formatted conservatively you might get away with it.

Comment: Also, please include the sample data *in the question*, *and* the regex engine you are using  in the tags.

Comment: thank you for quick response,


http://regexr.com/v1?38u5g is the link, where sample code is already placed. I have tried with below 2 regex code, but no luck.

RegEx1: '<a (.*?)><span (.*?)>(.*?)<\/span><\/a>'

RegEx2: '<a (.*?)><span (.*?)><img(.*?) \/><\/span><\/a>'

Comment: On [SO] is is strongly preferred that questions and answers do not depend on external links (especially if those links are flash based).

Comment: Sorry, and I have updated my post with sample text.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This captures the target `<img>...</img>` tag as group 1 of the match:

```
<a [^>]*>(<span [^>]*>)?(<img[^>]* \/>)(<\/span>)?<\/a>
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/Fbrp8Z5KpP#).

The trick here is to use `[^>]*` rather than `.*?` to consume only the attributes of the tag and thus correctly match the nearest parent.

Comment: Thank you Bohemian,  

Here, only some images are wrapping with span tag. But I have to get all the images with span tag or with out span tag. I have tried to write a condition(`(?(1)foo|bar)`) in RegEx but its not working.



`/<a [^>]*>(?(<span [^>]*>(<img[^>]* \/>)<\/span>)<span [^>]*>(<img[^>]* \/>)<\/span>|<img[^>]* \/>)<\/a>/`

Kindly help me to write a conditions in RegEx since I am totally new for RegEx. Thanks

Comment: @faruq I have altered the regex and updated the demo to include and example without a span. As long as your html is well formed enough, this new version will work.

Comment: thank you for your support, still I am unable to write the RegEx to fetch the images with or without span tag around the image. I have added the extra string to your demo which has both scenarios. Kindly help me out to get the output.

http://rubular.com/r/QMPMDpEbNF

Comment: @FaruqShaik that link uis not using the updated regex (that I changed to cater for your requirement of optional span - look carefully at my answer's regex and read earlier comments). I have updated the link you posted to use my current regex - see [link](http://rubular.com/r/VRcLlg7b3p). See if already works.

Comment: Its satisfying my requirement and thank you for your help to complete my RegEx task. Just for knowledge, I want to know the RegEx statement to make optional every tag which comes before/after the image tag .

EX: `<a>(<span>?)<img>(<span></span>)?(</span>)?</a>`